Why can't I return a nested `RwLockReadGuard` from a function?
I have greatly simplified my specific problem to the example below:
struct MyStruct {
    my_lock: RwLock<RwLock<u8>>
}

impl MyStruct {
    async fn my_function(&self) -> RwLockReadGuard<u8> {
        let outer_guard = self.my_lock.read().await;
        let inner_guard = outer_guard.read().await;
        return inner_guard;
    }
}

I'm getting the following error:
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `outer_guard`
  --> src/geolocations/geocode/client.rs:99:10
   |
98 |         let inner_guard = outer_guard.read().await;
   |                           ----------- `outer_guard` is borrowed here
99 |         return inner_guard;
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

In my mind, the lifetime of inner_guard is bound to the lifetime of my_lock which is bound to the lifetime of self. Why does Rust care at all about the fact that outer_guard is bound to the scope of the function with regards to returning inner_guard if the two are not bound to each other?
How can I return the second RwLockReadGuard<u8> from the function? Or at a minimum, a reference to the u8 value it's guarding?

"the lifetime of inner_guard is bound to the lifetime of my_lock" is right, but it's also a function local, it cannot live beyond the function (unless you return it), any references derived from it can't either.

@cafce25 So what's the solution to this problem? Is there some sort of design pattern that most people use for this scenario?

The only way I can see to make this work the way you want is by using a self-referential wrapper struct around both guards, which requires the use of unsafe to create. My guess is that this is an XY problem. What is your higher-level goal? There may be a better way to achieve that.

You can't return one RwLockReadGuard, but you can return RwLockReadGuard<RwLockReadGuard<u8>> or a wrapper struct around it.

@ChayimFriedman I don't think you can without creating a struct to hold both guards (using unsafe). Otherwise, what owns the outer lock?

Oh right, you can't use map() for this because read() doesn't return a reference..

@cdhowie What I'm trying to build is a client that grabs some data from an http server and caches the result in a HashMap<String, MyData>. The client can be called asynchronously so I have to put a RwLock around the HashMap and another RwLock around each entry in the HashMap to prevent race conditions at each level, effectively making my data structure a RwLock<HashMap<String, RwLock<MyData>>>. Hope that makes sense.

@ChayimFriedman map is unstable anyway. :(

Not with tokio, and you can switch to parking_lot.

Depending on whether you ever need a &mut to the inner data, you can use one of these approaches:

RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<MyData>>> and return a cloned Arc<MyData>.  This does not allow &mut access to the MyData but you may not need this. If you only need to read from it or replace the value entirely (which you can do by writing a new Arc to the map with just a write lock on the map), you can use this approach.
RwLock<HashMap<String, Arc<RwLock<MyData>>>> and return a cloned Arc<RwLock<MyData>>.  This offers the same capabilities as the other type, but allows writing at the expense of needing to lock to access the inner data.

Both approaches provide a kind of "snapshot" capability where accessing an entry value does not require holding a lock on the map itself.  In particular, when using the first approach, tasks that take an Arc can use a consistent point-in-time view of the cached data that will not change, even if the map is updated with a new value.
You might also consider looking into the moka crate, which provides implementations of both synchronous and asynchronous caching maps, both of which handle locking and eviction for you.

I don't need &mut access to MyData so looks like the first approach is better. However, being the stickler that I am, a side effect of this approach is that when writing an entry to the HashMap (which can take a long time due to the http request), all readers get locked out even when they're trying to read other entries unrelated to the one being written. This is why I wanted a second RwLock at the entry level for more granularity. It's not terrible, but do you think there's no way to accomplish that level of granularity with the Arc approach?

@AxiomaticNexus If that's an issue you might want to look at dashmap instead, which creates multiple shards that are locked independently. This splits up the bucket space allowing some level of parallel access (between buckets stored in different shards). Note that in the first approach in my answer, readers are only locked out if they haven't yet cloned the Arc. Once they have cloned an Arc and released their lock guard, there is no locking required to access the entry and writes to the map can happen concurrently.

I think I found a work around that allows for the granularity I wanted. I pulled the RwLock that was around the HashMap into its own separate field that wraps nothing (RwLock<()>), but still use it as if it were guarding the HasMap. MyData holds the Arc which contains the actual data being cached, and there is still a RwLock at the entry level inside the HashMap wrapping MyData (HashMap<String, RwLock<MyData>>). The downside to this approach is that I'm manually guarding the HashMap which can result in a race condition if I'm not careful, but I think it technically works.

@AxiomaticNexus That shouldn't work at all, and I'm not sure how it's better anyway. This means you require a &mut self to write to the map, at which point a lock is pointless because you already have exclusive access.

You're right. I forgot about the single &mut reference rule. I looked into the moka crate and it looks like it does what I need. I was really trying to avoid adding dependencies to the project, but looks like I'm not smart enough to figure this one out myself.
